# Avoid for loop using numpy matrices

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, matrix

I'm wondering that must be a way of doing the following without the **for** loop:

```
import numpy
from itertools import product as itprod

a = np.arange(120.).reshape(3,2,5,2,2)
fact = np.linspace(1,1.4,15).reshape((3,5))

for i,j in itprod(range(3),range(5)):
    a[i,:,j]*= fact[i,j]
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a for-loop?

Comment: @That1Guy: A Python for loop is a rather slow way of operating on Numpy arrays.  The idea of Numpy is to do vectorised high-level calls, so the actual looping can happen in optimised C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take advantage of broadcasting, you have to insert new axes for `fact` at the right places:

```
a *= fact[:, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```